# Responsive Web Design float position

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am trying to achieve the following in a two column float css design

[image]

My css for the two is this:

```
.div1 {
 width: 25%;
 float:left;
}

.div2 {
 width: 75%;
 float: right;
}

.container {
 width:960px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
 .div1, .div2 {
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 float: none;
 clear: both;
 }
 .container {
  width: 100%;
 }
}
```

my html is this:

```
...
<div class="container">
 <div class="div1">
 ... content inside
 </div>
 <div class="div2">
  <img src="photo_loc"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

I have Div I and Div II. Div I is 25% width and Div II is 75% width. When I go to 320px (iphone portrait) using responsive design Div II goes below Div I, which I assume is the normal process.

What I am trying to do is have Div II above Div I using floats, how can this be achieved through css?

Comment: we nned your HTML makup to answer your question

Comment: start with a mobile first approach, build your HTML for the mobile layout (ie Div2 first) then use CSS to rearrange the elements in the desktop view correctly.

Often the mobile version has a lot of the CSS formatting removed so if this is your starting structure displaying it correctly with a desktop width is much simpler then vice versa!

Comment: Actually div2 is 75%, I copied it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap the HTML positions of div1  and div2 around.

It may not be semantically correct in terms of how the page should be layed out but it will still work.

Keep the CSS the same and have your html like this

```
<div class="div2">Text for box 2</div>
<div class="div1">Text for box 1</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/u3Ng3/1/

Comment: Yikes, I made a mistake on div2 -- it's 75% not 25%.

Answer (score 2):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lax4d/)

```
.div1 {
width: 25%;
float:left;
background:orange;
}

.div2 {
width:75%;
float: right;
background:red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
.div1, .div2 {
width: 100%;
display: block;
float: none;
clear: both;
}
.div1{
position:relative;
top:100px;
}
.div2{
position:absolute;
top:0;
height:100px;
}
}
```

Comment: This would have been nice, if I knew the actuall height. But it can vary between screens.

Comment: Ok. Then swapping is best :)